# How to upload a file or folder in box using curl php.?

Tags: php, curl, box

I want to upload an image in to my box account to the root folder of it.
How can i achieve this.Below is my code,Please checkit.

**https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content**

**code**

```
    $json = json_encode(array(
                        'name' => 'spring.jpg', 
                        'folder' => array('id' =>'0')// 0 - uploads to main folder
                        ));
    $fields = array(
                  'attributes' => $json,
                  'file'=> new CURLFile('@C:\xampp\htdocs\box\spring.jpg')
              );

    $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json',          
        'Authorization: Bearer W1UkcTHsuuiDCA3Ej5n4xwMqoSGh0iVW'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

        var_dump($fields);

        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        print_r($response);
```

Comment: The provided link doesn't work. The code should be checked by you first, then you should tell us what is the problem/error - please tak a look at [ask].

Comment: i checked it but there shows no error and it is not uploading the file

Comment: You can debug curl operations - after the curl_exec() do something like: `if (curl_error($ch) === false) echo curl_error($ch);` There's also a useful function: `curl_getinfo()`, for instance: `echo curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);` which would give you the server response code.

Comment: after i use, echo curl_error($ch); it is showing this couldn't open file "@C:\xampp\htdocs\box\spring.jpg" and if i remove @ then it is showing nothing on the screen

Comment: thanks #Picard i have solved ths problem now and this is my new code

Comment: $attachmentPath = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\box\Notific.png';

$cfile = new CURLFile(@$attachmentPath);
$json = json_encode(array(
                        'name' => 'samayla notification picture', 
                        'parent' => array('id' =>'0')// 0 - uploads to main folder
                        ));
$fields = array('attributes' => $json,'file'=> $cfile);
$url = "https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content";

Comment: @mosin Hi. I'm trying to upload the file in box. But I can't Please explain me  :)

Comment: i have solved the problem now thanks for you comments